# Run Azure VM Extension Powershell script from git repository

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to deploy a VM and run an extensions powershell script using ARM Templates.
The script below is responsible to run the extentions for the VM.
As can be seen in the part:

```
 "commandToExecute": "[concat('powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File arm-modules/../../install.ps1 '
```

The powershell will execute the script file from that location. I want to save the .ps1 file in a git repository and pass the link to the file instead of the local folder.
Something like `"commandToExecute": "[concat('powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Uri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../install.ps1`
How can I achieve this?

```
"resources": [
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'), '/' ,parameters('virtualMachineName'), 'installGW')]",
        "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "tags": {
          "vmname": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]"
        },
        "properties": {
          "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
          "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
          "typeHandlerVersion": "1.7",
          "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
          "settings": {
            "fileUris": [
              "[parameters('scriptURL')]"
            ]
          },
          "protectedSettings": {
            "commandToExecute": "[concat('powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File arm-modules/.../.../install.ps1 ', if(equals(parameters('existingDataFactoryVersion'), 'V2'), listAuthKeys(parameters('irId'), '2017-09-01-preview').authKey1, listAuthKeys(parameters('irId'), '2015-10-01').key1))]"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to do it is to set URL `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../install.ps1` (URL must be accessible for Azure ARM) to `scriptURL` parameter (`"[parameters('scriptURL')]"` in `"fileUris"` settings) which is already in your template.

CustomScriptExtension will download all files `fileUris` into your VM to the extension folder, so you can use command as following:

```
 "commandToExecute": "[concat('powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File install.ps1 '
```

**Note:**

You can find CustomScriptExtension logs and downloaded files in VM:

```
C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension
C:\Packages\Plugins
```